# How can I show tray hidden icons (such as data connection)?

Tags: system-tray, user-experience

When not contextually relevant (ie. after a WiFi connection), the tray icons at the top of the screen disappear.

How can I force them to appear so that I can check (for example) my connection status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the icons appear temporarily by swiping your finger down from the top of the screen. To my knowledge, there's no way to force them to remain down all the time.

However, this does not work in applications that have chosen to hide the tray entirely such as Facebook, Twitter and Internet Explorer.

(FYI, pre-Mango the system tray colour could not be customized per-app so apps with custom colour schemes chose to hide it altogether)

Comment: Two things to note. If the clock is available in the top right, that means the application **hasn't** hidden the toolbar, and you can get to it. Also, you don't need to swipe down. A simple tap at the very top (try tapping the clock) works as well.

Comment: Also, you can view the tray in Internet Explorer. Tapping the app bar to bring it up (tap the ...) will cause the tray to display.